# Is there a GUI tool to show an archive information with ratio visualization?

Tags: archive

Is there a GUI tool to show an archive information with ratio visualization like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, however many compression/decompression tools will provide you with the ratio (eg the -l flag on gzip will provide a wide range of info including the ratio) so you could use this as an input to a graphing tool.